# jQuery make surrounding href select radio on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the surrounding url, when clicked, select the child radio button inside. The href is blocked so it makes the whole line clickable.

```
<a href="#" class="radio-click">
  <input type="radio" /> Test
</a>
```

I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is moot as having an `input` inside an `a` element is not valid HTML. Imagine the `input` is clicked. Does that mean the user wants to set focus in the `input` to type, or does it mean they want to go to the link in the `a` element?

From the description of what you're trying to achieve it sounds like you want ot use a `label` element instead:

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" />
  Test
</label>
```

Or alternatively:

```html
<input type="radio" id="foo" />
<label for="foo">Test</label>
```